# Функции поиска файла по пути к нему

Tags: visual-c++, файлы, c++

Здравсвуйте!
Задача такая - клиент-серверное приложение. Клиент отсылает строку - путь к файлу на сервере.
Сервер принимает эту строку, ищет этот файл у себя и отсылает поблочно клиенту.
Какие есть функции для поиска файла по пути?

Comment: Если путь уже дан, то остается только открыть файл по нему.

Comment: а как поделить файл на блоки для отправки серверу?

Comment: Его потом склеивать придется на сервере.

Comment: ну да, только отправлять поблочно надо, клиент передает и размер блока тоже. есть какая-нибудь функция для деления файл на блоки?

Comment: rar -v<size>[k,b] :) Слишком неопределённые вещи спрашиваете: какие блоки, нужны ли какие-то специальные заголовки у блоков, как отправлять - последовательно или в несколько потоков... Впрочем, любая из этих задач может быть решена элементарно, нужно только сформулировать что именно нужно.

Comment: Это функция fread() из stdio. Читайте man.

Comment: мм, open() - открыть файл, seek() - для перемещения по файлу, read() для чтения.

Если надо читать по 4Кб, то перемещаешься в начало файла, считываешь, посылаешь. перемещаешься на 4Кб снова посылаешь и т.д.

Comment: А скакать по файлу зачем?

Обычно в таких задачах клиент просит либо весь файл от заданного блока, либо интервал блоков.

Открыли, один раз спозиционировались, далее читаем блок - передаем, читеам следующий... и т.д.

Comment: Ну к вопросу "зачем" можно добавить вопрос "куда".